LibreOffice documents to latex with writer2latex
exporting LibreOffice documents to latex with writer2latex, I am getting this error message Error: Failed to execute Latex; see log for details

Is latex installed? What does the log say?

Why have you used tag [tag:fonts]? Wouldn't, e.g. [tag:libre-office] make more sense?

welcome! you need to give us a bit more information for people to do more than guess. but failing to execute latex definitely suggests latex is either not installed or not found.
